# How can I export several different rostopic messages to the same .txt file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to export several different rostopic messages (not the same type of message) to the same .txt file in MATRIX form in order to be imported easily into MATLAB for data treatment. What is a proper way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261445/how-can-i-export-several-different-rostopic-messages-to-the-same-.txt-file?/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to import data from ROS into MATLAB, you are probably best off recording [Rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag). Check out the tutorials to figure out how to use it. When you have recorded the bag file, it should not be a big problem to import in into MATLAB using the [MATLAB rosbag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosbag.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). [Here's](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/work-with-rosbag-logfiles.html) some more documentation.

For some more info about importing bag files into matlab, [look over here](http://answers.ros.org/questions/query:matlab%20rosbag/), there have been a number of questions on the topic.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1